# Hide checkbox text using CSS/Javascript

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a gridview and the first column has a checkbox to select every row. I have written some CSS for the checkbox but as the checkbox doesn't have any text within it nothing is displayed. If I include any text in the checkbox then the CSS works fine.

I don't need text or to hide the text (if dummy required) to make the look and feel the same throughout.

This is my CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -o-opacity: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    position:relative;
    padding: 3px 0 0 25px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    background: #88bbd4;
}
```

I need the grid column like the image shown here:
[image]

Comment: can you make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: simply add a checkbox in item template of first template field. you don't need any text to display it

Comment: @VikasRana : Yes, I have added that but the css doesn't get applied if I don't add any text to it.

Comment: Of course. Your css styles the labels which immediately follow the checkboxes. Now you don't have labels, how do you think that css will apply. It will only hide the checkboxes as you have specified opacity as 0.

Comment: @abhitalks: So, how to do this? I need checkbox with and w/o label but need single css for this.. please help

Comment: Does your css really work with labels? Could you show it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS just doesn't sync with what you are after. You don't need all that stuff. And why `border-radius`? Do you want them to look like radio buttons?

What you could do is simply this:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ZdyC7/***

*CSS*:

```
input[type="checkbox"]::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty in browsers except IE9 but I need the same looks in IE9.

Comment: It degrades gracefully in IE.